# Calling Stored Procedures is much slower than just calling insert and bulk insert is basically the same, Why?

Tags: python, mysql, bulkinsert, stored-functions

I have a table and a stored procedure like following,

```
CREATE TABLE `inspect_call` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cc_number` varchar(63) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created_at` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `updated_at` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `task_id` (`task_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=234031 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci 

CREATE PROCEDURE inspect_proc(IN task bigint,IN number varchar(63))
INSERT INTO inspect_call(task_id,cc_number) values (task, number)
```

I had assumed that calling the stored procedure would be (much) faster than just calling insert. But to my surprised that is NOT the case at all. When I insert **10000** rows records, the insert command takes around **4 minutes** while the stored procedure takes around **15 minutes**.

I have run the test many times to confirm that. The MySQL server is not a high end server but I don't understand why calling the stored procedure is much slower.

```
#using mysql-connector-python 8.0.31
command = ("INSERT INTO inspect_call (task_id,cc_number)"
           "VALUES (%s, %s)")
for i in range(rows): 
    cursor.execute(command, (task_id,f"{cc}{i}"))
    # cursor.callproc("inspect_proc", (task_id,f"{cc}{i}"))
cnx.commit()
```

BTW, I read some articles saying I can set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2` to improve the insert speed but I don't plan to do that.

--- update ---

From the answers I got I tried bulk insert(`executemany`) to see if there any improvement, but to my surprise there **isn't**.

```
cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
for i in range(int(rows/1000)):
    data = []
    for j in range(1000):
        data.append((task_id,f"{cc}{i*1000+j}"))
    cursor.executemany(command,data)
 cnx.commit()

 # no improvement compared to 

 cursor = cnx.cursor()
 for i in range(rows):
    cursor.execute(command, (task_id,f"{cc}{i}"))
```

I tried many times (also tried 100 record for one `executemany` shot) and find their performances are basically the same.

Why is that ?

--- update 2 ---

I finally figure out why insert is so slow! Because I run the script from my laptop and access the database from its external host name. Once I uploaded the script to the server and access the DB from inside the intranet, it is much faster. Inserting 10000 records takes around 3 to 4 seconds; inserting 100,000 records takes around 36 seconds. I did not network can cause such a difference!

BUT `executemany` didn't improve the performance in my case though.

Comment: "I had assumed that calling the stored procedure would be (much) faster than just calling insert." - why did you assume that? The stored procedure looks like just overhead to me.

Comment: The stored procedure for select is always faster, so I had assume that was the case for insert too.

Comment: In my understanding a stored procedure is faster when you have computation to do. It's done on the server-side, saving all the network exchanges to send records to the client and send back record to the server after computation.
Here you call your stored procedure as many time as you would have called insert(). So don't expect any benefit.
In your case you would benefit from `bulk insert`.

Comment: You say "in Python". Have you tried exactly the same experience but calling your stored procedure using another language ?

Comment: No I have not got a chance to do that because I was surprised to see the stored procedure is much slower.

Comment: @user2357112 please check my update. I got another surprise that `executemany` didn't improve the performance too.

Comment: How do you create the `Cursor` object ?
From the documentation : `curA = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)`

Comment: @0x0fba yes I used `cnx.cursor(buffered=True) ` actually you can verify that if you are interested.

Comment: Are you short of memory for records or indexes that would lead to disk swap on the server ?
Can you have more insight by monitoring the server ? innodb engine, memory usage, index, ...

Comment: Hi I finally find the reason why insert is so slow! Because I run the script from my laptop and access the DB from it external host name, once I uploaded the script to server and access the DB from internal, it is much faster. Sorry for the false alarm. BUT `executemany` didn't improve the performance though.

Answer (score 1):

Your example won't give credit to stored procedure because it won't use any advantages of stored procedure.

Main advantages of stored procedures are :

- it's compiled
- it saves network exchanges *(as computations operate on the server side)*

Imagine you have a logic enough complex not to be operated by UPDATE and you'd like to operate e.g. in Python, it requires :

- **select rows** -> *network traffic [server -> client]*
- **update rows** -> *quite slow : Python is interpreted, maybe even slower if you use an ORM like SQLAlchemy (objets have to be created in memory)*
- **send back updated rows** -> *network traffic [client -> server]*

Imagine the same example implemented with a stored procedure.
In that kind of example chances are that the stored procedure really shines.

In your example you don't have any logic but just insert rows.
It's an I/O bound use case. No or little gain to have a compiled procedure.
And you'll have as many network exchanges as if you used INSERT.
Whatever way rows have to be sent to the server.
Also no gain in the network traffic amount.

In your example maybe `bulk insert` could help reaching best performances.

Comment: But why is it much slower than insert ? At least they should roughly be the same.

Comment: Without looking a the code of a `Cursor` object it's likely that it maintains a context - at least an open connection to the database - that will be reused at each iteration in the loop.
On the contrary it's possible that the stored procedure has to open a socket (even if it's on the same host) and close it at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is unlike many other engines in that ordinary statements are reasonably fast -- and wrapping in a stored procedure may add more overhead than it saves.

You want faster? Batch the rows into a single `INSERT` (or, if there is a huge list, break it into clumps of 1000).

See `executemany()`.

Comment: To my surprise (again) `executemany` did not improve the performance either! I will update my question later

Comment: Hi I finally find the reason why insert is so slow! Because I run the script from my laptop and access the DB from it external host name, once I uploaded the script to server and access the DB from internal, it is much faster. Sorry for the false alarm. BUT `executemany` didn't improve the performance though.

Comment: @Qiulang - One way to measure the latency is via `SELECT 1;`